# How to get data from a JSON file without using a link?

Tags: javascript, json

This is my first time at working with a programming language, so I'm having trouble formulating the question. Hope it's clear this time around.

I have been given the following assignment.

There is a data object stored at https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json. I should remove the link from the code and instead add the information contained in that page into the code. In addition, I need to add three more super heroes into that list.

If you store the complete version in a .html file and open it in a web browser, you will see how the website looks like. I need to add three more superhoes to that list. Here is the original code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Our superheroes</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> </head>

<body>
    <header> </header>
    <section> </section>
    <script>
        var header = document.querySelector('header');
        var section = document.querySelector('section');
        var requestURL = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', requestURL);
        request.responseType = 'json';
        request.send();
        request.onload = function() {
            var superHeroes = request.response;
            populateHeader(superHeroes);
            showHeroes(superHeroes);
        }

        function populateHeader(jsonObj) {
            var myH1 = document.createElement('h1');
            myH1.textContent = jsonObj['squadName'];
            header.appendChild(myH1);
            var myPara = document.createElement('p');
            myPara.textContent = 'Hometown: ' + jsonObj['homeTown'] + ' // Formed: ' + jsonObj['formed'];
            header.appendChild(myPara);
        }

        function showHeroes(jsonObj) {
            var heroes = jsonObj['members'];
            for (var i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++) {
                var myArticle = document.createElement('article');
                var myH2 = document.createElement('h2');
                var myPara1 = document.createElement('p');
                var myPara2 = document.createElement('p');
                var myPara3 = document.createElement('p');
                var myList = document.createElement('ul');
                myH2.textContent = heroes[i].name;
                myPara1.textContent = 'Secret identity: ' + heroes[i].secretIdentity;
                myPara2.textContent = 'Age: ' + heroes[i].age;
                myPara3.textContent = 'Superpowers:';
                var superPowers = heroes[i].powers;
                for (var j = 0; j < superPowers.length; j++) {
                    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
                    listItem.textContent = superPowers[j];
                    myList.appendChild(listItem);
                }
                myArticle.appendChild(myH2);
                myArticle.appendChild(myPara1);
                myArticle.appendChild(myPara2);
                myArticle.appendChild(myPara3);
                myArticle.appendChild(myList);
                section.appendChild(myArticle);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried storing the information inside a .json file and referring to it, instead of providing a link in the code. If you store my complete code in a .html file and the above data from the second code instance in a file called squad.json, you will see that the only text displayed is the line with "Hometown:" and "formed:". Not even that line is complete, as they list "undefined" instead of the values they are supposed to contain, "Metro City" and "2016", accordingly. This is what my finished code looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Our superheroes</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> </head>

<body>
    <header> </header>
    <section> </section>
    <script>
        var header = document.querySelector('header');
        var section = document.querySelector('section');
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'squad.json', true);
        request.onload = function() {
            var squad = JSON.parse(this.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < squad.length; i++) {
                console.log(squad[i].squadName + squad[i].homeTown + squad[i].formed + squad[i].secretBase + squad[i].active + squad[i].members);
            }
        }
        request.send();
        request.onload = function() {
            var superHeroes = request.response;
            populateHeader(superHeroes);
            showHeroes(superHeroes);
        }

        function populateHeader(squad) {
            var myH1 = document.createElement('h1');
            myH1.textContent = squad['squadName'];
            header.appendChild(myH1);
            var myPara = document.createElement('p');
            myPara.textContent = 'Hometown: ' + squad['homeTown'] + ' // Formed: ' + squad['formed'];
            header.appendChild(myPara);
        }

        function showHeroes(squad) {
            var heroes = squad['members'];
            for (var i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++) {
                var myArticle = document.createElement('article');
                var myH2 = document.createElement('h2');
                var myPara1 = document.createElement('p');
                var myPara2 = document.createElement('p');
                var myPara3 = document.createElement('p');
                var myList = document.createElement('ul');
                myH2.textContent = heroes[i].name;
                myPara1.textContent = 'Secret identity: ' + heroes[i].secretIdentity;
                myPara2.textContent = 'Age: ' + heroes[i].age;
                myPara3.textContent = 'Superpowers:';
                var superPowers = heroes[i].powers;
                for (var j = 0; j < superPowers.length; j++) {
                    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
                    listItem.textContent = superPowers[j];
                    myList.appendChild(listItem);
                }
                myArticle.appendChild(myH2);
                myArticle.appendChild(myPara1);
                myArticle.appendChild(myPara2);
                myArticle.appendChild(myPara3);
                myArticle.appendChild(myList);
                section.appendChild(myArticle);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Again, the task is to include the text from the second code instance without using a link. Whether it'd be from a .json file or directly into the code. This is my first major assignment as part of my training. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "without using a link".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON data can be directly used as javascript objects, so, if you're allowed to store the data in the code without referring to an external resource this should work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Our superheroes</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster+One" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

      <header>

      </header>

      <section>

      </section>

    <script>
    var header = document.querySelector('header');
    var section = document.querySelector('section');

  var superHeroes = {
  "squadName" : "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown" : "Metro City",
  "formed" : 2016,
  "secretBase" : "Super tower",
  "active" : true,
  "members" : [
    {
      "name" : "Molecule Man",
      "age" : 29,
      "secretIdentity" : "Dan Jukes",
      "powers" : [
        "Radiation resistance",
        "Turning tiny",
        "Radiation blast"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "Madame Uppercut",
      "age" : 39,
      "secretIdentity" : "Jane Wilson",
      "powers" : [
        "Million tonne punch",
        "Damage resistance",
        "Superhuman reflexes"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "Eternal Flame",
      "age" : 1000000,
      "secretIdentity" : "Unknown",
      "powers" : [
        "Immortality",
        "Heat Immunity",
        "Inferno",
        "Teleportation",
        "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "Eternal Flame 2",
      "age" : 1000000,
      "secretIdentity" : "Unknown",
      "powers" : [
        "Immortality",
        "Heat Immunity",
        "Inferno",
        "Teleportation",
        "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
    }
  ]
};
  populateHeader(superHeroes);
  showHeroes(superHeroes);

function populateHeader(jsonObj) {
  var myH1 = document.createElement('h1');
  myH1.textContent = jsonObj['squadName'];
  header.appendChild(myH1);

  var myPara = document.createElement('p');
  myPara.textContent = 'Hometown: ' + jsonObj['homeTown'] + ' // Formed: ' + jsonObj['formed'];
  header.appendChild(myPara);
}
function showHeroes(jsonObj) {
  var heroes = jsonObj['members'];

  for (var i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++) {
    var myArticle = document.createElement('article');
    var myH2 = document.createElement('h2');
    var myPara1 = document.createElement('p');
    var myPara2 = document.createElement('p');
    var myPara3 = document.createElement('p');
    var myList = document.createElement('ul');

    myH2.textContent = heroes[i].name;
    myPara1.textContent = 'Secret identity: ' + heroes[i].secretIdentity;
    myPara2.textContent = 'Age: ' + heroes[i].age;
    myPara3.textContent = 'Superpowers:';

    var superPowers = heroes[i].powers;
    for (var j = 0; j < superPowers.length; j++) {
      var listItem = document.createElement('li');
      listItem.textContent = superPowers[j];
      myList.appendChild(listItem);
    }

    myArticle.appendChild(myH2);
    myArticle.appendChild(myPara1);
    myArticle.appendChild(myPara2);
    myArticle.appendChild(myPara3);
    myArticle.appendChild(myList);

    section.appendChild(myArticle);
  }
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, instead of requesting the data from an external resource

```
var requestURL = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
    var superHeroes = request.response;
    populateHeader(superHeroes);
    showHeroes(superHeroes);
}
```

you can add the data to the code

```
  var superHeroes = {
  "squadName" : "Super hero squad",
  "homeTown" : "Metro City",
  "formed" : 2016,
  "secretBase" : "Super tower",
  "active" : true,
  "members" : [
...
```

new heroes can then be added the same way I added

```
...
    {
      "name" : "Eternal Flame 2",
      "age" : 1000000,
      "secretIdentity" : "Unknown",
      "powers" : [
        "Immortality",
        "Heat Immunity",
        "Inferno",
        "Teleportation",
        "Interdimensional travel"
      ]
    },
...
```

Comment: There are no such things as "JSON objects". Using that term will only confuse people.

Comment: @Cobwebber then I'm not seeing something - what doesn't work? The contents of the page look the same (if you run the first snippet from your question and the runnable snippet I posted). (apart from the "Eternal Flame 2" I added to the end of the one I posted)

Comment: @Kristaps After pasting the text, I replaced every instance of jsonObj with the var name superHeroes. Was this a mistake? Did I have to replace something else instead, or something else in addition?

Comment: @Cobwebber As long as you're consistent in what you rename that shoudn't be an issue (in this case that would just mean that the functions would see a local var called superHeroes instead of the global one). I highlighted the only parts that had to be changed right after the runnable snippet

Comment: @Kristaps I see I omitted the calls of the populateHeader() and showHeroes() functions. After adding them, it works just fine. Thank you very much!